# LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol init__init__

Tags: python, cubes

I'm trying to learn how to use Cubes server by following this tutorial [Slicing and Dicing with Cubes - Light-weight OLAP Framework and Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYas6qMr17Q&t=2792s) I installed git desktop and tried the following commands using git bash as instructed at 4:10 of the video

```
$git clone https://github.com/Stiivi/cubes.git
$git clone https://github.com/Stiivi/cubes-examples.git

$pip install sqlalchemy werkzeug
$cd cubes
$python setup.py install
```

but I get the error

> LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol init__init__
>   build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\grako\test\grammar__init__.lib : fatal
>   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals error: Setup script exited with
>   error: command
>   'C:\Users\saiki\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual
>   C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

How can I resolve this?